# Azure mysql server provisioning

Tags: azure, azure-arm-template, azure-dns, azure-resource-manager

Trying to create an Azure mysql flexible server through the portal I get the following error message.

> "code": "InvalidPrivateDnsZoneSubscription",
> "message": "The subscription 'xxxxxxx-xx-xx-xxx-xxxxxx' of the private DNS zone 'xxxxxxxx.mysql.database.azure.com' is in valid, it is not registered for '2'."

The dns zone is required because I'm deploying to a vnet rather than public access.

The dns zone has already been created, the vnet and subnet has already been created.

The deployment should just link all the existing parts together and in fact part of the deployment works as the subnet has updated the `delegated to` attribute.

The same also happens if I download the template for the deployment and attempt a custom deployment using that template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this resolved the issue, I can't answer why it happened in the first place.

During the first attempt the process failed (The reason remains unknown), however part of the deployment had completed. The parts that did work included creating the virtual network link within the private dns zone that was selected.

Removing the virtual network link within the dns zone unblocked the deployment.